# about mechanisms on creating a class object

Tags: java

I saw a class "AttributeSelectedClassifier" was once created in the following ways:

```
AttributeSelectedClassifier classifier = new AttributeSelectedClassifier();

classifier.setClassifier(base);
classifier.setEvaluator(eval);
```

This above one looks natural to me. But how about the following one.

```
classifier = new AttributeSelectedClassifier();
((AttributeSelectedClassifier)classifier).setClassifier(base);
((AttributeSelectedClassifier)classifier).setEvaluator(eval);
```

I think it should be right, but I am not quite sure about the way of of defining classifier as ((AttributeSelectedClassifier)classifier), how to understand this usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the below code. Person implements the `CanWalk` interface. If you assign a `Person` to `CanWalk` interface as shown in the main method, which is a common practice, you can only invoke the methods that are specified in the `CanWalk` interface i.e. `walk()`. If you want to invoke `f()`, that **isn't** declared in the `CanWalk` interface, then you would use the 2nd mechanism you have specified in your post. i.e. **cast** it to `Person` class and then invoke the method.

It is a good practice for the user's of the API (main method here) to use the correct abstraction while working with an object. For e.g. if the client is mainly focused on moving Person's then it should use CanWalk. This way client is not effected by changes to the Person class that are not related to movement. Read [this article](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/10/18/coding-role-based-interfaces/) for more details.

```
interface CanWalk
{
  void walk();
}

class Person implements CanWalk
{
  void walk()
  {
     System.out.println("I am walking");
  }

  void f()
  {
    ///some arbitrary method
  }
}

public stativ void main(String a[])
{
   CanWalk cw=new Person();
   ((Person)cw).f();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This means that the classifier variable is declared as a superclass or superinterface of `AttributeSelectedClassifier`, and that you need to call a method which is not defined in the class or interface, but only on `AttributeSelectedClassifier`. This notation *casts* the variable to `AttributeSelectedClassifier`:

```
Object classifier = new AttributeSelectedClassifier();
// classifier is a AttributeSelectedClassifier, but references as Object
// to call the following method, we need to cast it to AttributeSelectedClassifier
((AttributeSelectedClassifier)classifier).setClassifier(base);
((AttributeSelectedClassifier)classifier).setEvaluator(eval);
```

This is usually the sign of a design problem. Either the methods should be in the superclass or interface, or the variable should be declared as `AttributeSelectedClassifier`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
((AttributeSelectedClassifier)classifier)
```

isn't "defining" or "declaring" classifier - it's *casting* it. Presumably in this case `classifier` is declared as some superclass of `AttributeSelectedClassifier`. The code isn't particularly clear though. I'd rewrite the second bit of code (assuming you can't change the declaration of `classifier`) to:

```
AttributeSelectedClassifier temp = new AttributeSelectedClassifier();
temp.setClassifier(base);
temp.setEvaluator(eval);
classifier = temp;
```

That way you get to use all the methods of `AttributeSelectedClassifier` before assigning a value to the less-strongly-typed `classifier` variable.

(I'd probably use a clearer name than `temp`, but we don't have enough context to work out what such a name would be.)

Answer (score 1):

By doing `((AttributeSelectedClassifier)classifier)` you are casting ("*forcing*") the `classifier` object to behave like an instance of `AttributeSelectedClassifier`.

The `classifier` variable was probably previously declared as a superclass of AttributeSelectedClassifier.